# ¿Cómo especificar a que server debe apuntar una consulta?

Tags: sql-server

Buenas tardes comunidad,

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto, y tengo 3 instancias de SQL SERVER en 3 servidores distintos, el asunto es que cada server tiene una base de datos igual y quiero ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado que existe en las BDs especificando cuál server debe utilizar. ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso? Investigando encontré este código, pero me da error donde están los 2 puntos:

```
:CONNECT devserver
use [my_database]
SELECT * FROM my_table
```

Gracias de antemano.

OJO: el código anterior es solo para ejemplificar lo que quiero hacer y que eso es lo que encontré.

Answer (score 0):

El codigo que pusiste esta correcto, solo necesitas habilitar el SQLCMD mode.

Para habilitarlo en tu query actual, Selecciona en la barra del Management studio, Query -> SQLCMD Mode.

Para Habilitarlo siempre para los nuevos queries, en el Management Studio ve a tools -> Options -> Query Execution -> SQL Server -> General y selecciona "By Default, Open new queries un SQLCMD mode"

Ya que se habilite tu query deberia de funcionar.

```
:CONNECT devserver
use [my_database]
SELECT * FROM my_table
```